# JavaScript library set this to an element

Tags: javascript

I am working on a jQuery like javascript library. The syntax vill go as follows:

```
tex(selector).function();
```

In my javascript library, I have this:

```
(function(){
  var tex = function(selector){
    //selection code here
  },
  tex.prototype = {
    // prototype functions here
  }
})();
```

The problem that I have is how do I set `this` to equal the element. I have already tried `this = document.getElement...` but it didn't work. I know jQuery does this somehow but I haven't how.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do it when you're calling a function, typically by using [`Function#call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) or [`Function#apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3):

```
function foo() {
    console.log("name = " + this.name);
}
var obj = {name: "Fred"};
foo.call(obj); // Outputs "Fred"
```

There, we call the `foo` function using `call`, passing in `obj` as the value to use as `this` during the call.

Applying that to a DOM element:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("My id is " + this.id);
}
var elm = document.getElementById("whatever");
foo.call(elm); // "My id is whatever"
```

The value to use as `this` during the call is the first argument to `call` and `apply`. The only difference between the two is how you pass arguments to the function (`foo`, in our example above): With `call`, you pass them as subsequent discrete arguments:

```
theFunction.call(thisArg, firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg);
```

With `apply`, you give it an *array* of args:

```
var args = [firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg];
theFunction.apply(thisArg, args);

// or (of course)
theFunction.apply(thisArg, [firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg]);
// Note -------------------^-----------------------------^
```

So a more complete example:

```
function foo(firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg) {
    console.log("name = " + this.name);
    console.log("firstArg = " + firstArg);
    console.log("secondArg = " + secondArg);
    console.log("thirdArg = " + thirdArg);
}
var obj = {name: "Fred"};

// These two calls do exactly the same thing:
foo.call(obj, "one", "two", "three");
foo.apply(obj, ["one", "two", "three"]); // Note the [ and ]
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does this by passing the selected elements as `context` to the callback function.

For instance...

```
tex.prototype = {
    // prototype functions here
    someMethod: function(callback) {
        callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

You can pass any javascript object for the context, so `this` in the example above could be your selected element(s).

Edit:

For clarity. You could do this in your tex function.

```
var element;
var tex = function(selector){
    element = document.getElementById(selector);
}
```

And then in the first example, use `element` instead of `this`.

As a side note, your tex variable isn't currently accessible outside of your self-executing anonymous function.

Comment: but what would I put inside the tex function itself?

Comment: Your tex function would take your selector, use it to get some DOM elements. Keep a reference in your tex function to your element(s), and that is what you will pass to the callback functions in your prototype methods.

Comment: Edited my answer above to reflect my last comment.